# Modules not permanently loaded

Tags: powershell, module

I'm trying to run a script that uses `Start-BitsTransfer`. However whenever I open Powershell I have to re-install the `BitsTransfer` module each time. This also means that I cannot run scripts that call Powershell to run commands, since the module thinks it is not installed.

[image: An example image is here]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the module loaded every time just put that line `import-module BitsTransfer` into one of the PowerShell profiles. From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx)

- `%windir%\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1` This is for all users of the computer and for all shells.
- `%windir%\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.Power­Shell_profile.ps1` This is for all users of the computer, but it is only for the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.
- `%UserProfile%\Documents\Windows­PowerShell\profile.ps1` This is for the current user only and all shells.
- `%UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Micro­soft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` This is for the current user only and only for the Microsoft.PowerShell shell.

**Note**: The links above are cmd based environment variables and will not work directly in PowerShell. In PowerShell you would use the provider `$env`. So for example:

```psh
$path = "$($env:windir)\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1"
# Assuming the directory '$($env:windir)\system32\Windows­PowerShell\v1.0' exists...
"Import-Module BitsTransfer" | Set-Content $path -Force
# This will OVERWRITE anything already there. This is just an example for reference.
```

Its not a case of installed..... it just needs to be imported. I do the same with the `ActiveDirectory` module.

And as [CB.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520612/cb) says:

> Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, modules are imported automatically when any cmdlet or function in the module is used in a command. This feature works on any module in a directory that this included in the value of the `PSModulePath` environment variable.

Comment: just a side node: Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, modules are imported automatically when any cmdlet or function in the module is used in a command. This feature works on any module in a directory that this included in the value of the PSModulePath environment variable.

Comment: @CB. Did not know that. Thanks.